# Read filepaths from text file and modify each of them

Tags: python, filenames

I have a text file (filenames.txt) which contains over 200 file paths:

```
/home/chethan/purpose1/script1.txt
/home/chethan/purpose2/script2.txt
/home/chethan/purpose3/script3.txt
/home/chethan/purpose4/script4.txt
```

Out of the multiple lines present in each of these files, each of them contain a line which is a filename like `Reference.txt`. My objective is to replace `.txt` in *Reference.txt* with `.csv` in every file. As a beginner of Python I referred to several questions in stackoverflow on similar cases and wrote the following code.

My code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#filename modify_hob.py

import fileinput

    f = open('/home/chethan/filenames.txt', 'r')
    for i in f.readlines():
        for line in fileinput.FileInput(i.strip(),inplace=1):
            line = line.replace("txt","csv"),
            f.close()
    f.close()
```

When I run my code, the contents of txt files (script1, script2..) mentioned above are wiped away, i.e., they won't be having a single line of text inside them! I am puzzled with this behavior and not able to find out a solution.

Comment: Why are you doing `f.close()` both inside and outside the loop?

Comment: One is to close script files one after another, another is to close filenames.txt after the process is complete.

Comment: But there is only one `f`, so how is it supposed to know that the inner one is really some other file?  (And even if you did have an inner `f`, that would be really poor design.)

Comment: I was unsure of how it works. I am yet to learn best code design practices.

Comment: The `FileInput` iterator is handling the inner file I/O itself; you do not need or want an explicit `close` invocation.  Meanwhile the one you are doing inside the loop is prematurely closing the file list.

Comment: Alright, now I have removed the inner `f.close()`. However the result has not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going (untested):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
#filename modify_hob.py

# Open the file with filenames list.
with open('filenames.txt') as list_f:

    # Iterate over the lines, each line represents a file name.
    for filename in list_f:

        # Rewrite its content.
        with open(filename) as f:
            content = f.read()
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(content.replace('.txt', '.csv'))
```

In your code below, `f` is set to the open file object of `filename.txt` and
nothing else. That is what you are closing in both the last two lines.

Also, you are not writing anything back to the files, so you can't expect your
changes to be written back to the disk. (Unless the `fileinput` module does some
dark magic that I'm missing.)

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/chethan/purpose1/script1.txt\n'. Earlier until I added `i.strip()` this new line error used to come. In the above code where can I add it?

Comment: @ChethanS. We are reading the file name from the list file into the variable `filename`. So that's the one you need to modify. Use `filename = filename.strip()` as the first statement in the `for` loop.

Comment: No problem. But more than getting it working, I wish you understand what's going on. Let me know if something's not clear still.

Comment: Shrikant, I got the code working when I appended `.strip()` to `filename` in open statements. When I used `filename = filename.strip()` in for statement, I got invalid syntax error for **=**. While I replied earlier I just thought both would work!

Comment: @ChethanS., Check your indentation. If that's not the problem, put the error you see in the question so I can see what's going wrong.